# jQuery NiceScroll, scroll the page when the div hits bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicescroll

I'm using [nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/), it works and is quite interesting. The way I'm using it is on a div, like this :

[image]

And is great, but, I want to be able to scroll the whole page if the scrollable area (the div) reaches the bottom.

Here is the function I'm using to initialize NiceScroll:

```
$(function () {
    $(".log").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor:"rgba(64, 58, 65, 0.50)",
        cursorborder: "1px solid rgba(64, 58, 65, 0.49)",
        cursorborderradius: "0",
        preservenativescrolling: "false",
        bouncescroll: false
    });
});
```